# Android : Unread message update in icon

Tags: android, notifications, icons, skype

I'm developing an android application with communication integrated. My application have to show number of unread messages via app icon, it's will be look like that skype, facebook or etc. I can not found any solutions to perform it, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

It works well for most of the devices.
PS. Nexus devices (or, more specific, the google launcher) does not support this!

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working fine. Android is difference IOS so i have to using there library for this function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass token with a message if a message is read or not. 
Suppose we have a token 0 for read messages and 1 for unread messages.
If message read then make token 0 else it is 1. 
To count the total number of unread messages, count the total number of unread messages (where token=1) from the list.

You can use [this](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge) repo or use any repo from this [link](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/140)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found the solution :)